# Wicket: Need to implement an AjaxTabbedPanel with tab error indicators

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.6

I have an AjaxTabbedPanel, and each tab may contain content which is invalid. I want to indicate this to the user by highlighting the tabs with errors, using a red background.

As an experiment I implemented the tabbed panel's `newLink()` method, and as you can see the `onClick()` method iterates over all the tab links of the parent panel and appends a CSS class attribute value to render a red background.

But none of my tabs are being highlighted.

I can find no relevant example for doing this, but it's possible someone may have done something similar, and can offer some advice.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected WebMarkupContainer newLink(String linkId, final int index)
{
    return new IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink(linkId)
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            setSelectedTab(index);
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.add(IndicatingAjaxTabbedPanel.this);

                int tabIndex = 0;
                for (ITab tab : (List<ITab>)getTabs()) {
                    Component link = IndicatingAjaxTabbedPanel.this.get("tabs-container:tabs:" + tabIndex++ + ":link");
                    if (link != null) {
                        link.add(AttributeAppender.append("class", "invalidValue"));
                        target.add(link);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This looks valid, so my only guess is, that your path "tabs-container:tabs:" + tabIndex++ + ":link" is wrong. Did you checked that?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying a different strategy, using onComponentTag(). Will post code if it works

Answer (score 2):

The following does the job for me. It relies on you providing an `AbstractTab` implementation class, which implements a marker interface

```
public interface IValidatingTab {
    public boolean valid();

    public void setValid(boolean valid);
}


/** 
    My Tab implementation
**/
public class SiteConfigTab extends AbstractTab implements IValidatingTab {

    private boolean valid;

    ...

    @Override
    public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
        // Return your Panel (containing all the UI components of the tab)
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

    public boolean valid() {
        return valid;
    }
}
```

So the components on each tab (textfields, checkboxes etc.) will do some kind of validation, and set the validity flag on the tab.

Now, I've extended `AjaxTabbebPanel` and implemented the `newLink()` method as follows. The `onComponentTag()` does the business of checking the tab's validity flag, and setting the CSS class if not valid.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected WebMarkupContainer newLink(String linkId, final int index)
{

        IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink link = new IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink(linkId)
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                setSelectedTab(index);
                if (target != null)
                {
                    target.add(IndicatingAjaxTabbedPanel.this);

                }


                onAjaxUpdate(target);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onComponentTag(final ComponentTag tag)
            {
                super.onComponentTag(tag);

                ITab tabPanel = (ITab)getTabs().get(index);
                String cssClass = tag.getAttribute("class");

                if (cssClass == null) {
                    cssClass = " ";
                }

                if (tabPanel instanceof IValidatingTab) {
                    if (!((IValidatingTab)tabPanel).valid()) {
                        cssClass += " invalidValue";
                    }
                }


                tag.put("class", cssClass.trim());
            }
        };

        return link;
}
```